# String appears differently depending on use scenario

Tags: c#, json, wpf, treeview

Getting some odd behavior with JSON data which is being loaded into an observablecollection.

Here's an example of the JSON import, and how my folder path is shown.

```
  {
 "projectNumber":"16000",
 "projectName":"Sample Project",
 "Directory":"@\"C:\\Users\"",  }
```

So far I've been able to use the data as expected after loading into my observablecollection. For example, the messagebox shows (selectedfolder) in the messagebox as intended: @"C:\Users"

This is the path I want my treeview to use. Oddly, it's not using that but instead uses the original path format from my JSON import instead ("@\"C:\Users\"") and throws an "Illegal characters in path" error.

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Items.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeView.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
    }

    private static TreeViewItem CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = directoryInfo.Name };
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            directoryNode.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            directoryNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = file.Name });

        return directoryNode;

    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Project selectedProject = comboBox.SelectedItem as Project;
        selectedfolder = selectedProject.Directory.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(selectedfolder);

        if (selectedProject != null)
        {
            this.ListDirectory(treeView, selectedfolder);
        }
```

Anybody see what I'm missing here, and why the same string would appear differently depending on how it's being used?

Answer (score 3):

The `@""` string literal is used to help write code that has strings with backslashes in it.  This bit of code, for instance, contains a reference to a valid path, and the `@""` bit just tells the C# compiler to treat backslashes differently than normal C-style strings:

```
string example1 = @"C:\Users";
Debug.WriteLine(example1); // Outputs C:\Users
// This works
var temp1 = new DirectoryInfo(example1);
```

Once you actually embed the `@""` bit in a string, you end up with a string that contains `@` and `"` characters in it, which isn't going to be a valid path on Windows.

```
string example2 = "@\"C:\\Users\"";
Debug.WriteLine(example2); // Outputs @"C:\Users"
// This throws an exception
var temp2 = new DirectoryInfo(example2);
```

In other words:  Using `@""` is fine for C# code, but for a JSON object, you'll need to change your JSON text to be something like this, using `\` to escape characters, so it's a valid path after the JSON deserializer finishes parsing the string:

```
{
    "projectNumber":"16000",
    "projectName":"Sample Project",
    "Directory":"C:\\Users",  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That was clearly the answer. Thanks so much, Anon! What was throwing me off was how the string showed in a messagebox exactly how I would use it in a path reference. Newbie mistake!